# How to square a custom view when layout_height and layout_width are set to have different magnitudes?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

As per my understanding when user specifies a views height/width in pixels/dp, the view receives EXACTLY spec mode. EXACTLY spec mode means that the view must use this size. Suppose I want to make sure my view remains a square. How can that be achieved if the user sets different values for layout_height and layout_width.

Answer (score 0):

Override onMeasure for your custom view, determine what the smallest dimension is, and set both your width and height to that minimum dimension.

Something like:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int specWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int specHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int lesserDimension = (specWidth > specHeight)?specHeight:specWidth;
    setMeasuredDimension(lesserDimension, lesserDimension);
}
```